# React Smooth Scroll But Not On Init

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, web, progressive-web-apps

I'm building a chat app using ReactJS. In Skype or WhatsApp, we see that if we click on a chat, it loads from the last. However, I want to add this feature to my app.

I came up with the solution `scrollIntoView({ behaviour: "smooth" })` method. But if I click on a chat, it scrolls all the way down to bottom. But I want it already scrolled to bottom on mount.

Can you please give me any suggestion on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you could do is attach an onload event listener to the chat or div or whatever you are using so what will happen is, as soon as you click on the chat it will load and while loading it will scroll all the way to bottom

I have never worked with react but this should do the trick....